# setTimeOut not working in recursive function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sorting, recursion, settimeout

I am creating a sorting visualizer. For iterative sorting algorithms, my code works perfectly but for quick sort and merge sort it does not. The function does not wait and immediately returns output but I have to show changes slowly by animations.Following is my code.

```
const delay = (time) => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, time));
  };
const quickSortHelper = async(arr, a, b) => {
    if (b > a) {
      document.getElementById(a).style.backgroundColor="green"
      let pivot = getPivot(arr, a, b)
      await delay(2*animationSpeed)
      setArray([...arr])
      document.getElementById(a).style.backgroundColor="#343434"
      await delay(2*animationSpeed)
      quickSortHelper(arr, a, pivot - 1)
      await delay(4*animationSpeed)
      quickSortHelper(arr, pivot + 1, b)
    }
  }
  const quickSort = () => {
    setStartSorting(true)
    let arr = [...array]
    console.log(arr);
    quickSortHelper(arr, 0, arr.length - 1)
    console.log('ended');
    setStartSorting(false)
  }
  const getPivot = (arr, a, b) => {
    let pivot = arr[a]
    var i = a
    var j = b
    while (j > i) {
      while (pivot >= arr[i] && i<=b) {
        i++
      }
      while (pivot < arr[j] && j>=a) {
        j--
      }
      if (j > i) {
        let temp = arr[i]
        arr[i] = arr[j]
        arr[j] = temp
      }
    }
    let temp =pivot
    arr[a] = arr[j]
    arr[j] = temp
    return j
  }
```

The console.log('ended') is executed immediately as soon as I run the function and states are also updated immediately.

Comment: Why have this be async at all?

Comment: @TimRoberts Because otherwise setTimeout will run parallelly. Hence I have wrapped setTimeout in a promise and used async-await for the function to wait until setTimeout is executed competely.

Comment: `quickSortHelper` is `async` so when you call it and not `await` the next line will be executed before it can conclude.